# How to make group (if specific field are same text) in loop?

Tags: php, loops, data-structures

I tried render data in loop and if `extend_tag` field have same text group in one container.
I only know hard code like below, loop data base on how many known `extend_tag` group, but actually the `extend_tag` numbers is unknown might be `tag_` and any digit , any idea how to solve it?

data

```
[tag] => Array (
  [0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [extend_tag] => tag_0 
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 2 
    [extend_tag] => tag_11 
  ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
    [id] => 3 
    [extend_tag] => tag_4 
  ) 
)


  <ul class="container">
  <?php foreach($rows['tag'] as $eachRowsTag) { ?>
    <?php if ($eachRowsTag['extend_tag'] == 'tag_0') { ?>
    <li>><?php echo $eachRowsTag['id']; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>

  <ul class="container">
  <?php foreach($rows['tag'] as $eachRowsTag) { ?>
    <?php if ($eachRowsTag['extend_tag'] == 'tag_1') { ?>
    <li>><?php echo $eachRowsTag['id']; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>

  ...
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you are doing and what the problem is? I don't really understand.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried to loop data and get to know if each array ['extend_tag'] value same to another then make them render in one container

Comment: but there is unknown how many different ['extend_tag'] value, so I can't coding like above what I did.  the ['extend_tag'] value have rule is 'tag_' + digit

Answer (score 0):

Why not group them first, then iterate over the resulting array. Something like the following.

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  $grouped[$tag['extend_tag']][] = $tag;
}
// Now $grouped is something along the lines of:
// [
//   'tag_0' => [
//     [ 'id' => 1, 'extend_tag' => 'tag_0'],
//     ..
//   ],
//   ..
// ]

foreach($grouped as $extend_tag => $tags) {
  echo "All tags in $extended_tag.";
  foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag['id'];
  }
}

// For something like:
// All tags in tag_0.
// 1
// 4
// All tags in tag_1.
// ..
```